# Regex for multiline email addresses?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a `RegEx` for multiple line email addresses.
For example:

1) Single email:

```
johnsmith@email.com  - ok
```

2) Two line email:

```
johnsmith@email.com
karensmith@emailcom  - ok
```

3) Two line email:

```
john  smith@email.com - not ok
karensmith@emailcom
```

I've tried the following:

```
((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*(\r\n)?)+)\r*
```

But when I test it, it seems to still match ok if there is 1 valid email address as in example 3.

I need a rule which states **all** email addresses must be valid.

Comment: It is very hard to build a rgex to correctly (to the RFC grammar) a single email address (most practical regexes will only a validate a subset of the grammar – but that's enough for real usage). Therefore better to split on spaces (and other acceptable separators), then validate each address in isolation. This will also allow you to highlight just the invalid ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
^(((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*(\r\n)?\s?)+)*)$
```

Check the beginning of the string using '^' and the end using '$'.
Allow an optional whitespace character with '\s?'.

Try out http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html for testing regex expressions.

Comment: Did some quick initial tests and seems to do the job - poyfect!

Comment: Cool. I only check for a single whitespace character. You might have more between addresses. If you do, change the '\s?' to '\s*'.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this only accept newline characters instead of just whitesapce, otherwise the emails could be entered on the same line?

Comment: Change to `^(((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*(\r\n)?\n?)+)*)$` for single addresses on each line.

Answer (score 1):

I'd split the string on `[\r\n]+` and then test each address individualy.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you probably need a multiline option at the end of your regexp (in most cases `/m` after the regexp).

**Edit** You might also want to add anchors `\A` and `\z` to mark the beginning and end of the input data. Here is a [good article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) on anchors.

**Edit** Quick and dirty example working in Ruby:

```
/\A\w+@\w+\.\w+(\n\w+@\w+.\.\w+)*\z/
```

Will produce:

```
"test@here.pl\nthe@bar.pl".match(/\A\w+@\w+\.\w+(\n\w+@\w+\.\w+)*\z/)
=> #<MatchData "test@here.pl\nthe@bar.pl" 1:"\nthe@bar.pl">
"test@here.pl\nthebar.pl".match(/\A\w+@\w+\.\w+(\n\w+@\w+\.\w+)*\z/)
=> nil
"test@here.pl".match(/\A\w+@\w+\.\w+(\n\w+@\w+\.\w+)*\z/)
=> #<MatchData "test@here.pl" 1:nil>
"test@here".match(/\A\w+@\w+\.\w+(\n\w+@\w+\.\w+)*\z/)
=> nil
```

You can improve the regex and it should work. The key was to use `\A` and `\z` anchors. The `/m` modifier is not required.

Comment: And a comment to my answer - I agree with Richard, it is very hard to write a regexp to match e-mail address ([indepth explanation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)). Depending on a language, it might also be better to just split the input data on a new-line and check each line individually.

Comment: Tried it but no luck, can you provide an example?

Comment: See the edit. I provided wrong anchors, my fault. `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a line, whereas I should use `\A` and `\z`.